# I get an EADDRINUSE problem but nothing uses the 3000 port. How is this possible?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu

I am following a tutorial on nodejs and I get an error.

That's my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.listen("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("<h1>Hello, there!</h1>")
});

app.listen("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.send("Contact me at obiwankenobi@falcon.com")
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000")
});
```

That's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-express-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a project on how to start your own server.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Adam Marasli-Zaade",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

And when I am hitting: node server.js, that's the error I am getting:

```
adam@Omen-hp:~/Desktop/Angela/my-express-server$ node server.js
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use /
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1260:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1325:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1423:5)
    at Function.listen (/home/adam/Desktop/Angela/my-express-server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adam/Desktop/Angela/my-express-server/server.js:5:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1304:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

System info:

``````
                          ./+o+-       adam@Omen-hp
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 19.10 eoan
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-26-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Node Version: 10.15.2
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      NPM Version: 6.13.6
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.3
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.  
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i5-7300HQ @ 4x 3.5GHz
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: GeForce GTX 1050
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

I have tried restarting the system, I have tried recreating the project, I have tried every command to find out what uses port:3000 and kill it, the problem is that I can't find anything that uses it, I have disabled atom-liver-server in case that's the problem because it uses port:3000, I don't know what else to do.

Thank your for your time.

Adam

Comment: You indicated that your problem is solved by accepting an answer. There's no need to add "[SOLVED]" to your title. (That's the convention on some sites, but not here.)

Comment: Thank you, I will correct that.

Comment: No need, I already did.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probleme is this chunk:

```js
app.listen("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("<h1>Hello, there!</h1>")
});
```

You are trying to listen on a socket path.
I assume you want to use `app.get(...)`.
Same for your `/contact` path

Take a short look on the express.js docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen_path_callback

Comment: @AdamMarasli-Zaade Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line type:

> **pkill -9 nod**e

then start up your prog

to see the port activity for your machine:

> **sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P**
>
> // or for ubunut try below
>
> **netstat -anp | grep apache**

Comment: can you post what your port activity is please (with command from above)